# SFDX orgs resetting between Bitbucket Pipelines steps

Tags: salesforcedx, ci, pipelines

I'm trying to set up sfdx on Bitbucket Pipelines.

It's going well but I'm facing a weird issue when using the [steps](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html#Configurebitbucket-pipelines.yml-ci_step) feature.

Here's a snippet of my build file:

```
- step:
            name: Auth. with DevHub
            script:
                - sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant -i $CLIENT_ID -f jwt/server.key -u $DEVHUB_USERNAME --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias DevHub
                - sfdx force:org:list
        - step:
            name: Create Scratch Org.
            script:
                - sfdx force:org:list
                - sfdx force:org:create -f environments/scratchorg1-scratch-def.json -v DevHub -a bitbucket_build_$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
```

Here's what the first force:org:list outputs:

```
+ sfdx force:org:list
=== Orgs
     ALIAS   USERNAME                            ORG ID              CONNECTED STATUS
───  ──────  ──────────────────────────────────  ──────────────────  ────────────────
(D)  DevHub  davin.casey+sfdx-trial@pexlify.com  00D1r000002cUfcEAE  Connected
No active scratch orgs found. Specify --all to see all scratch orgs
```

and the second:

```
+ sfdx force:org:list
ERROR:  No orgs can be found. 
Try this:
Use one of the commands in force:auth or force:org:create to add or create new scratch orgs.
```

When you read the documentation for Pipelines, that appears to be expected behaviour:

> Each step in your pipeline will start a separate Docker container to
>   run the commands configured in the script. Each step can be configured
>   to:
>
> Use a different Docker image. 
>   Configure a custom max-time. 
>   Use specific caches and services.
>   Produce artifacts that subsequent steps can consume.

So it's spinning up a fresh image for each step, but we can pass artifacts to subsequent steps. Fine.

So I updated my build file to look like:

```
- step:
                name: Auth. with DevHub
                script:
                    - sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant -i $CLIENT_ID -f jwt/server.key -u $DEVHUB_USERNAME --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias DevHub
                    - sfdx force:org:list
                artifacts:
                    - .sfdx/**
                    - config/**
                    - environments/**
                    - sfdx-project.json
                    - jwt/**
            - step:
                name: Create Scratch Org.
                script:
                    - sfdx force:org:list
                    - sfdx force:org:create -f environments/scratchorg1-scratch-def.json -v DevHub -a bitbucket_build_$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
                artifacts:
                    - .sfdx/**
                    - config/**
                    - environments/**
                    - sfdx-project.json
                    - jwt/**
```

Now, I can see the artifacts being prepared & used in each step.

'Auth. with DevHub teardown':

```
Build teardown
10s
Searching for artifacts matching .sfdx/**
Compressing artifact /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.sfdx/orgs/test-oitz1ujqhgka@example.com/metadataTypeInfos.json
Compressing artifact /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.sfdx/orgs/test-oitz1ujqhgka@example.com/sourcePathInfos.json.bak
Compressing artifact /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.sfdx/orgs/test-oitz1ujqhgka@example.com/sourcePathInfos.json
Compressing artifact /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.sfdx/sfdx-config.json
Compressed artifact in 0 seconds
Uploading artifact of 10 KB
Successfully uploaded artifact in 1 seconds
Searching for artifacts matching config/**
Compressing artifact /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/config/testorg11384827171-scratch-def.json
Compressing artifact /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/config/scratchorg1-scratch-def.json
Compressing artifact /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/config/project-scratch-def.json
Compressing artifact /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/config/sfdx-trial-scratch-def.json
Compressed artifact in 0 seconds
Uploading artifact of 739 bytes
Successfully uploaded artifact in 1 seconds
Searching for artifacts matching environments/**
Compressing artifact /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/environments/project-scratch-def.json
Compressed artifact in 0 seconds
Uploading artifact of 241 bytes
Successfully uploaded artifact in 1 seconds
Searching for artifacts matching sfdx-project.json
Compressing artifact /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/sfdx-project.json
Compressed artifact in 0 seconds
Uploading artifact of 278 bytes
Successfully uploaded artifact in 1 seconds
Searching for artifacts matching jwt/**
Compressing artifact /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/jwt/server.csr
Compressing artifact /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/jwt/server.crt
Compressing artifact /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/jwt/server.key
Compressed artifact in 0 seconds
Uploading artifact of 2 KB
Successfully uploaded artifact in 1 seconds
```

'Create Scratch Org. build setup':

```
Artifact ".sfdx/**": Downloading
Artifact ".sfdx/**": Downloaded 10 KB in 0 seconds
Artifact ".sfdx/**": Extracting
Artifact ".sfdx/**": Extracted in 0 seconds
Artifact "config/**": Downloading
Artifact "config/**": Downloaded 739 bytes in 0 seconds
Artifact "config/**": Extracting
Artifact "config/**": Extracted in 0 seconds
Artifact "environments/**": Downloading
Artifact "environments/**": Downloaded 239 bytes in 0 seconds
Artifact "environments/**": Extracting
Artifact "environments/**": Extracted in 0 seconds
Artifact "sfdx-project.json": Downloading
Artifact "sfdx-project.json": Downloaded 278 bytes in 0 seconds
Artifact "sfdx-project.json": Extracting
Artifact "sfdx-project.json": Extracted in 0 seconds
Artifact "jwt/**": Downloading
Artifact "jwt/**": Downloaded 2 KB in 0 seconds
Artifact "jwt/**": Extracting
Artifact "jwt/**": Extracted in 0 seconds
Artifact ".sfdx/**": Downloading
Artifact ".sfdx/**": Downloaded 10 KB in 0 seconds
Artifact ".sfdx/**": Extracting
Artifact ".sfdx/**": Extracted in 0 seconds
Artifact "config/**": Downloading
Artifact "config/**": Downloaded 739 bytes in 0 seconds
Artifact "config/**": Extracting
Artifact "config/**": Extracted in 0 seconds
Artifact "environments/**": Downloading
Artifact "environments/**": Downloaded 241 bytes in 1 seconds
Artifact "environments/**": Extracting
Artifact "environments/**": Extracted in 0 seconds
Artifact "sfdx-project.json": Downloading
Artifact "sfdx-project.json": Downloaded 278 bytes in 0 seconds
Artifact "sfdx-project.json": Extracting
Artifact "sfdx-project.json": Extracted in 0 seconds
Artifact "jwt/**": Downloading
Artifact "jwt/**": Downloaded 2 KB in 0 seconds
Artifact "jwt/**": Extracting
Artifact "jwt/**": Extracted in 0 seconds
Artifact ".sfdx/**": Downloading
Artifact ".sfdx/**": Downloaded 10 KB in 0 seconds
Artifact ".sfdx/**": Extracting
Artifact ".sfdx/**": Extracted in 0 seconds
Artifact "config/**": Downloading
Artifact "config/**": Downloaded 739 bytes in 0 seconds
Artifact "config/**": Extracting
Artifact "config/**": Extracted in 0 seconds
Artifact "environments/**": Downloading
Artifact "environments/**": Downloaded 241 bytes in 0 seconds
Artifact "environments/**": Extracting
Artifact "environments/**": Extracted in 0 seconds
Artifact "sfdx-project.json": Downloading
Artifact "sfdx-project.json": Downloaded 278 bytes in 0 seconds
Artifact "sfdx-project.json": Extracting
Artifact "sfdx-project.json": Extracted in 0 seconds
Artifact "jwt/**": Downloading
Artifact "jwt/**": Downloaded 2 KB in 0 seconds
Artifact "jwt/**": Extracting
Artifact "jwt/**": Extracted in 0 seconds
```

So they appear to be working correctly, however the orgs are STILL not carrying across to subsequent steps.

Does anyone know why this might be? I assume the org. list is being stored in a local file somewhere, but I've added everything I can see as an artifact so I've no idea where else to look. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you login, can you run something like `sfdx force:org:display --verbose -u DevHub --json | jq -r .result.sfdxAuthUrl` to get the auth URL, store the value securely somewhere, then run `sfdx force:auth:sfdxurl:store -f <secure location> -a DevHub -d` in each step?

This is how I solve a similar challenge across build/release phases for the [Salesforce Buildpack in Heroku Pipelines](https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-buildpack).

Edit: I just remembered that we don't generate the `sfdxAuthUrl` if the org authenticated through `jwt:grant` because the flow doesn't return a refresh token. I avoid this issue in the buildpack by asking people to manually auth to their dev hub locally then generating the `sfdxAuthUrl`. Perhaps you can do that and then store it in some kind of config var on Bitbucket?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Wade, this worked perfectly. I've no problem generating the file manually, it only needs to be done once anyway.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Actually I'm getting a follow on problem. In one step I auth using the json file method and then create a scratch org, that works perfectly. Next step I reauth using the same file (successfully) but then force:org:list returns no scratch orgs (only the DevHub) so my next step (push to scratch org) fails. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Yes: http://www.wadewegner.com/2018/01/jwt-oauth-with-scratch-orgs/

You might need to stick with JWT. Two thoughts: 1) use only one step or 2) re-auth with JWT at the beginning of each step.