# What is needed to persist sfdx org between CI runs

Tags: salesforcedx, ci

I'm running Github Actions and trying split multiple UI tests into separate jobs. Part of the task is to copy the file system artefacts for next job to use (each job starts in a fresh container). I wanna re-use same org for next job which runs in a different container.

There's [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254740/jenkins-docker-and-sfdx-share-sfdx-cache-between-docker-containers) and [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219872/sfdx-orgs-resetting-between-bitbucket-pipelines-steps) which sort of explains that copying `.sfdx` from home/root directory should be enough, but I still receive `No AuthInfo found for name`.

Strangely enough there doesn't seem any orgs being added to a zip file I'm uploading to artefacts storage (really I should be using github cache, but I haven't figure it out yet):

```
Run zip -r ciorg.zip .sfdx
  adding: .sfdx/ (stored 0%)
  adding: .sfdx/sfdx-config.json (stored 0%)
```

Is there additional store that sfdx uses?

Link to [workflow definition file](https://gist.github.com/sjurgis/d776c25f3182cb947baefdb05ce49391).

Answer (score 0):

The auth info is stored in `~/.sfdx/"username@domain.tld.json"` for each login. If those files aren't persisted, you're not logged in. You could try:

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant -u username@domain.tld\
 -f path/to/jtw-key-file -i myConnectedAppOAuthId\
 -s -a myOrgAlias
```

You'll need to store the JWT token somewhere, so be sure you can retrieve it. Take care with it, as it is the same as a password.

Comment: Well, I am logged... In first step I create an org and second step I log in again (via jwt).

Comment: Here's my workflow: https://gist.github.com/sjurgis/d776c25f3182cb947baefdb05ce49391

Comment: I think I've confused home dir .sfdx vs repo .sfdx...

Comment: @dzh Yeah, the auth is stored globally, not in the project.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there's two folders, both named `.sfdx` - one in the repo/project folder, one in the user home.

To pack up everything in one command:

`zip -r ciorg.zip $PWD/.sfdx ~/.sfdx`

To unpack (**warning**: overwrites existing files!):
`unzip -o ciorg/ciorg.zip -d /`

You can [view example](https://gist.github.com/sjurgis/2ff09c8045af0cd482d1e28529692120) of how is this used in my Github Actions CI flow.